# R minus operation creates imprecise value

Tags: r

I came across with a stupid question today for R. I am using R version 3.4.4 and RStudio version 1.1.423.

```
test <- 1682.2- 1681.8
test
0.400000000000091
```

Isn't the value `test` supposed to be exactly 0.4?

Comment: 0.400000000000091 is equal to 0.4: `all.equal(0.400000000000091, 0.4)`

Comment: I think mussuse's comment is misleading. Adjust your mental framework when working with computers to not ever use "exactly equal" for non-integer numbers. If there are decimals, there needs to be a precision tolerance.